# Hom(V,W) is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

WTS: Hom(V,W) which is the set of all linear maps is a vector space.

The question I have is that, isn't Hom(V,W) a subset of W? Because Hom(V,W) is just the set of all linear maps from V to W, so why can't I just show that it is a subspace?

Comment: A map from $V\to W$ is not an element of $W$.

Comment: Because a linear map is not a vector.

Comment: @Bernard A linear map is very capable of being a vector, it being a member of the vector space $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$!

Comment: I mean not a vector of the vector spaces at hand ($V$ and $W$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the image of a particular function $V\to W$. By itself, a function $f\colon V\to W$ is a single object. You can define a vector space structure on the set of all such maps since it contains a zero element (the zero map) and you can scale any linear map by a constant: if $f\colon V\to W$ is linear and $c$ is a scalar, then $cf$ defined by $(cf)(v)=c(f(v))$ is another linear map.

Comment: That's not enough for a vector space, you also need addition of linear maps (which, of course, works the same way),

Answer (score 2):

**Hom(V,W) is a set of homomorphisms**(vector space homomorphism)/linear maps **from V to W**, which forms vector space! whilst what you're thinking is just **image of V with particular element f of Hom(V,W)**(*i.e. f(V) is subspace of W*). These two are different things!